# What does a generic type that `extends boolean = false` mean?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to grok the [API of React Select](https://react-select.com) by looking at [its TypeScript definitions](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/940a50b1a579b279b82c1efc5608a92eb422919e/packages/react-select/src/stateManager.tsx#L15) I came across this chunky state definition:

```
declare type StateManagedSelect = <
  Option = unknown,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>
>(
  props: StateManagerProps<Option, IsMulti, Group> &
    RefAttributes<Select<Option, IsMulti, Group>>
) => ReactElement;
```

There are two things that stand out to me:

1. `IsMulti extends boolean = false` is assigned an actual *value*?! What does this mean? I thought TS type generics did not allow for actual *values*, only default *types*
2. `Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>`. Does assigning a default type to `Group` that is identical to the thing it extend do anything? Could it not just have been `Group extends GroupBase<Option>`, period?

Comment: The equals operator in typescript generics declares a default value, i.e. ``IsMulti extends boolean = true`` means that ``IsMulti`` is true by default, but can be overriden by the user.

Comment: @Tracer69 - I think you meant `false` in there, to match the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. `IsMulti extends boolean = false` is assigned an actual value?! What does this mean? I thought TS type generics did not allow for actual *values*, only default *types*

`false` is a type (as is `true`). They're [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) that are both subtypes of `boolean`. From that link (you have to scroll down a bit):

> There’s one more kind of literal type: boolean literals. There are only two boolean literal types, and as you might guess, they are the types `true` and `false`. The type `boolean` itself is actually just an alias for the union `true | false`.

So what `IsMulti extends boolean = false` is saying is that the `IsMulti` type parameter expects a `boolean` type argument (`true` or `false`), and if you don't supply it, it defaults to the type `false`.

> 2. Does assigning a default type to `Group` that is identical to the thing it extends do anything? Could it not just have been `Group extends GroupBase<Option>`, period?

Yes, it does something: It makes it optional. If it were just `Group extends GroupBase<Option>`, you'd have to supply a type argument for it when you used `StateManagedSelect`. Because the type parameter has a default, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

`T extends X = Y`, where `Y` is a subtype of `X`, simply gives a default type for `T`. `boolean` is equivalent to `true | false`, therefore `false` is a subtype of `boolean`.

Here's a simplified example. Without using a default subtype:

```
declare function fn<T extends boolean>(arg?: T): T

let x = fn(true) // type of `x` is `true`
let y = fn(false) // type of `y` is `false`
let z = fn() // type of `z` is `boolean`
```

Now with the default subtype:

```
declare function fn<T extends boolean = false>(arg?: T): T

let x = fn(true) // same as before
let y = fn(false) // same as before
let z = fn() // type of `z` is now `false`
```